# If/Else Statement in JSP- How to create a Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

The error I have is I'm unsure how to complete this code after searching everywhere on the internet.

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; width: 1000px; text-align:right;">
<%
if ( session.isNew() )
{out.println("Login" );}
else
out.println("Logout");
%>
</div>
```

So what this is supposed to do is if the session is NEW (User has not logged in) it should say Login. If session not new (If user is already logged in) It should say Logout. So my code does this now.(I think)

Now my problem is creating a Hyperlink for Login/Logout. When login is clicked, it should redirect to Login.jsp page.(Logout.jsp) for Logout.

Very new Web developer so open to all suggestions.

Comment: Hope you can figure it out on your own with these links, for more information google "Scriptlet". http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaou.html, http://www.jsptut.com/mixing.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to call your if statement, then break out of the JSP into HTML and write whatever you like. As long as the if statement is built correctly, it doesn't really matter what's inside of it. It'll look something like:

```
<% if( session.isNew() ) { %>
    <a href="/login">Login</a>
<% } else { %>
    <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
<% } %>
```